# ¿Como usar el componente select2 en blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

hola comunidad estoy intentando usar el componente `select2` descargado del nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEvaldas.Blazor.Select2/ pero la verdad no se cual es mi error, ya logre traer los registros de la base de datos para cargar el componente pero no se me muestran los nombres sino aparece el texto `blazorapp.shared.models.categoria`.

este es mi código:

```
<span>Select 2</span>

<Select2 TItem="Categoria"
         Id="simple-string-example"
         Data="@SimpleStringList"
         @bind-Value="@ValueSelected">
</Select2>
<span>Currently selected value: @ValueSelected</span>
<br />

@code {

    private EditContext EditContext { get; set; }
    private Select2<SomeInnerObject> ProvidedSelect2Ref { get; set; }
    public SomeObject FakeObject { get; set; } = new SomeObject { SomeName = "Name" };
    private List<Categoria> SimpleStringList { get; set; } = new List<Categoria>();
    private List<SomeInnerObject> InnerObjectList { get; set; }
    private Categoria ValueSelected { get; set; }

    private SomeInnerObject FooObject = new SomeInnerObject { InnerName = "Inner Foo" };

    protected async override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        if (firstRender)
        {
            //SimpleStringList.Add("Foo");
            //SimpleStringList.Add("Bar");
            //SimpleStringList.Add("Baz");

            var responseHttp = await repositorio.Get<List<Categoria>>("api/Categoria");
            SimpleStringList = responseHttp.Response;           

            InnerObjectList = new List<SomeInnerObject> { FooObject, new SomeInnerObject { InnerName = "Inner bar" } };
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                InnerObjectList.Add(new SomeInnerObject { InnerName = $"Inner bar{i}" });
            EditContext = new EditContext(FakeObject).AddDataAnnotationsValidation();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

este es el resultado en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que SimpleStringList es una lista del tipo Categoria, entonces al hacer .ToString() esta obteniendo el tipo del objeto

Usted puede hacer 2 cosas para solucionar este problema,
La primera es sobreescribir el metodo ToString para la clase Categoria,

O la mas recomendada y la que ademas recomienda el autor del componente para trabajar con objetos complejos puede pasar como parametro TextExpresion indicando la propiedad que se usara como identificador Ejemplo:

```
<Select2 TItem="Categoria"
        Id="simple-string-example"
        Data="@SimpleStringList"
        @bind-Value="@ValueSelected">
        TextExpression="@(Categoria=> Categoria.Nombre)"
</Select2>
```

(Asumiento que categoria posee la propiedad nombre y quieres que esta salga en la lista)

Para mas informacion consulta los ejemplos en el repositorio del autor del componente:

https://github.com/nevaldas/Blazor/blob/master/demo/Demo.WebAssembly/Pages/Index.razor

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda me funciono perfecto